# i just want to print the data in alert but ever time it alert me [object Object] but i want that it will show my table data row

Tags: javascript, json, alert, stringify

```
$.post("Hirarchi/addHirarchi",
    {/*'id':hirarchiId,*/'hirarchiName':hirarchiName,'level':HirarchiLevel},
        function(data) {


            $('#lblMessage').html (data);
            $('#txtHirarchiName').val('');
            $('#txtHirarchiLevel').val('');

                        var data = $.parseJSON(data);

                        $.each(data, function(a,b,c) {


                            alert(data);

                        });

        });
```

Comment: $.each(data, function(index,value,list) {


                            alert(value);

                        });
you can not pass object to alert. If you give object to it, it will [Object Object]. alert parameter must be string

Comment: if you want to alert data each time, you can JSON.stringify(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not pass object to alert. If you give object to it, it will [Object Object]. alert parameter must be string

```
//for Each loop code
$.each(data, function(index,value,list) { 
  alert(JSON.stringify(value)); //if you want to alert each object then use
  //data will not be accessible inside $.each you can access the same using 3rd parameter which list
  alert(JSON.stringify(list));
});
```

But the thing is why you gave alert in $.each and alerting same data.
I'm assuming it is part of some functionality in your code. But that is not good practice to do.

Update 1.

Here is your answer with rendering table.

Code

```
drawTable(data);  /// call this line from your ajax success

function drawTable(data) {
    var tData = data.tblHirarchi
    for (var i = 0; i < tData.length; i++) {
        if (tData[i] != null) {
            drawRow(tData[i])
        }
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $("<tr />")
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData[0] + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData[1] + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData[1] + "</td>"));
}
```

[Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sEwM6/1151/)

Comment: {"tblHirarchi":[[2007,"ceo",1],[2078,"aa",11],[2079,"bb",22],null]}

when i alert data it just alert like this 
but i want want to print only one row 
and one thing more 
how can i print the row of this data in a table row

Comment: #pankaj i just tried your code but 
alert(JSON.stringify(list));
alerts me UNDEFINED

Comment: no bro 
but now i want to print the data in a table row like a grid view

Comment: $.post("Hirarchi/addHirarchi",{/*'id':hirarchiId,*/'hirarchiName':hirarchiName,'level':HirarchiLevel},
   function(data) {
       
      
    $('#lblMessage').html (data);
    $('#txtHirarchiName').val('');
    $('#txtHirarchiLevel').val('');
});


i have recieving the table data in DATA but dont know how to print it in a table row

Comment: @SalisTariq i have attached fiddle. hope that will be helpful to you.

Comment: @SalisTariq  have you checked my answer and fiddle..does it helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of print just data, print something like:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

See, if that solves your problem.